# Test data in php

Tags: php, testing, random, textfield

I want to generate test data for testing. What I need:

I will have a list of 30 names. For each name I need to fill in the start and finish position. The position is between 1 and 30.

So I wanted to use `RAND()` in php but I have a problem what I can't find a good way for.

Every position can only be used once. So if I press on a button "generate data" I want for all 30 names a start and finish position without duplicate position. So in the start i will use 1 - 30 and for the finish 1 - 30 as well.

I need this data in textfield. Is there a simple function for this? Or do you know how I can do this without having to fill in 60 textfields every test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  will use [shuffle](http://php.net/shuffle) (twice),

something like

```
$arr = range(1, 30);
$first_numbers_position = shuffle($arr);
$second_numbers_position = shuffle($arr);
```

if you have already array with the names
you can use this function

Very simple shuffle function preserving key with value

```
function shuffle_assoc( $array )
{
   $keys = array_keys( $array );
   shuffle( $keys );
   return array_merge( array_flip( $keys ) , $array );
}
```

Comment: i will get 59 results in my array. Is there something i do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might get you started:

```
$names = array(/*...*/);
$l = count($names);
$rand = array();
for ($i = 0; $i<$l; $i++) {
  $rand[] = $i;
}
shuffle($rand);
for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
  $names[$i]['start'] = $rand[$i];
}
```

Or:

```
$names = array(/*...*/);
shuffle($names);
for ($i = 0, $l = count($names); $i < $l; $i++) {
  $names[$i]['start'] = $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your code to actually generate the data dynamically you could try something like this site http://www.generatedata.com/